# How to tell who is logged in to a website

Tags: php, mysql

Users must log into my website and this is controlled via sessions. As an admin, I would like to be able to see who is logged in at any given time.

I could have a database field capturing who is logging in and logging out, but this does not account for sessions expiring and the logouts resulting from that. How can I tell who has active sessions on my website?

Comment: if session is set, set a boolean flag

Comment: ...and set that boolean flag differently on logout. It's a *vice-versa* thing.

Comment: there's that crazy ajax thing you can use to hit the db every x minutes, then you can count the absence of hits to know people have left the site without logging off.

Comment: How about a complicated captcha every 3 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely advise using the database, and actually storing sessions in a database with the appropriate timeout. With that said, sessions ARE stored serverside as well, and can be fetched.

`print_r(scandir(session_save_path()));` would echo out any active sessions. Iterating through them and retrieving the relevant data should not be difficult.

Comment: You should only make your own session management if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Dagon I'd definitely agree it's not a viable solution - but it *is* an option, regardless of how inefficient it is.

Comment: @Dagon I would say I suggested another approach, wouldn't you? :)

Comment: [*Like this?...*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNnAvTTaJjM) @Dagon Edit: awww you deleted your comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yhea sorry, to nasty, even for me :-)